# AirConsole Unity plugin - WebGL build does not work while Unity debugger works

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

We've created a small demo of Unity3D with AirConsole-plugin which is working in Unity debugger. (If I press play, the browser opens, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't, one can restart Unity and then it works.)
If we create a release or a developer build, it does no longer work. It will load the image correctly, but the controllers (virtual+phone) stay 'loading' most of the time. Sometimes they reach the first correct HTML page, but then the message they send doesn't seem to arrive on the screen-side.
When I click the 'Open Exported Port' after the build, it doesn't work too, except for once.

One error message I got once:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postQueue' of undefined"

This error message appears always:
"pre-main prep time: 176 ms         UnityLoader.js:1
Module.printErr @ UnityLoader.js:1"

Do you know what these error messages mean?

Comment: The Uncaught TypeError message should indicate a line of code in your controller file, which might help you find the issue.

Apart from that: are you sure you've imported everything correctly?

Comment: You mean the import of files into Unity? I'll have a look. 
===
Details: 
VM192 UnityLoader.js:3386 pre-main prep time: 94 msModule.printErr @ VM192 UnityLoader.js:3386doRun @ blob:http%3A//192.168.1.3%3A7842/a1c4b233-2afc-4aaa-ba85-b9433253e5b5:3646758(anonymous function) @ blob:http%3A//192.168.1.3%3A7842/a1c4b233-2afc-4aaa-ba85-b9433253e5b5:3646770
VM192 UnityLoader.js:3382PlayerConnection initialized from  (debug = 0)

Comment: What does this error mean?   `UnityLoader.js:1 pre-main prep time: 603 msModule.printErr @ UnityLoader.js:1doRun @ blob:http%3A//airconsole.septem.ch/056d3d86-5c6b-4b2b-812d-c299b85fbbd5:36(anonymous function) @ blob:http%3A//airconsole.septem.ch/056d3d86-5c6b-4b2b-812d-c299b85fbbd5:36
UnityLoader.js:1 Initialize engine version: 5.3.3f1 (910d71450a97)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a lot, but this seems to solve the problem: Be sure to attach the event listeners in the Awake method, as they do in basic example application.

```cs
public class AirConsoleService : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        // register events
        AirConsole.instance.onReady += OnReady;
        AirConsole.instance.onMessage += OnMessage;
        AirConsole.instance.onConnect += OnConnect;
        AirConsole.instance.onDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
        // etc. ...
    }
    // etc. ...
}
```

My problem was that my `AirConsoleService` was static and not a `MonoBehaviour` to be sure that there is only one instance of `AirConsoleService`. It works perfectly for the debug 'play' mode, but in the release build, the AirConsole somehow does not know the deviceID which sent the message (this means, we get -1 from method `ConvertDeviceIdToPlayerNumber`. And this explains why the controllers don't get any signal from the screen.

My solution: I've attached it as a component to the AirConsole object.

Further notes:

- Anti-Virus may block content.
- Your PC/server has to be fast.
- During development, log the deviceID and the playerID and the current active deviceIDs.
- Often restart Unity or the integrated webserver of the plugin